# SQLite difference between dates as year

Tags: sqlite, julian-date

```sql
Select
    round ((JulianDay('Chk_date1')) - JulianDay('HireDate'))/365.25 AS TimewithCo
from 
    employee;
```

I'm trying to find out difference between these two dates in years but it's giving null.can anyone please guide me.

| Hiredate | Chk_date1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2011-06-17 | 2022-06-01 |
| 2009-09-21 | 2022-06-01 |
| 2013-01-13 | 2022-06-01 |

Comment: Remove the single quotes from the column names.

Comment: Single quotes delimit strings.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select
    round ((JulianDay(Chk_date1)) - JulianDay(HireDate))/365.25 AS TimewithCo
from 
    employee;
```